# When a TCP socket's BeginRecieve fires onDataReceived delegate, what happens with subsequent packets received before BeginReceive is called again?

Tags: .net, sockets

In other words, what happens to new packets received between the start of execution of the delegate:

```
public static void Read_Callback(IAsyncResult ar){ 
    StateObject so = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState; 
    Socket s = so.workSocket;

    int read = s.EndReceive(ar);

    if (read > 0) {
            so.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(so.buffer, 0, read));
```

and the next the next call of beginReceive on that socket?

```
            s.BeginReceive(so.buffer, 0, StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE, 0, 
                                 new AsyncCallback(Async_Send_Receive.Read_Callback), so);
}
```

Is a second onDataReceived executed in parallel, or does the data queue up in a buffer and the next beginReceive fires the delegate immediately after being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is queued to a buffer. These callbacks are executed on the thread pool, so as soon as `BeginReceive` is called, the callback may be fired.

Comment: but it would only be one at once, correct? IE it wouldn't execute 2 callbacks in parallel? Because it's in the "thread pool" is what is making me wonder if "perhaps it spawns one thread per packet" etc.

Comment: No, it could call two callbacks in parallel, if one `BeginReceive` callback called `BeginReceive` again right away. Normally, a `BeginReceive` callback will pass the data to another thread or queue or something and then call `BeginReceive` just before returning, so it's not an issue.

Comment: yes that's how I've been doing it-- writing the data to a buffer and then calling BR at the end.

If that buffer were locked for a short time, blocking the callback...what about then? It still should just block and write as soon as available, right?

I've got a TCP stream being written to my buffer out of order occasionally, even though the stream itself (packets captured with wireshark) are arriving in order (even if they were out of order, TCP can handle receiving them out of order)...

Comment: If the callback is blocked, then it won't be able to call `BeginReceive`, so another callback can't be started.

Comment: well this is not my fault then so I can't be held responsible! :)

Comment: I'd check the buffer locking logic.

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke BeginReceive explicitely, though, you shouldn't do it until the callback completed. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx#Y53 for a proper example.
As for the more general tcp question, I suppose it depends on the tcp stack implementation, but there is most certainly a buffer where data are accumulated at a lower level. Depending on the sender's setup, it might block when the buffer is full if nobody on the receiver side calls the proper receive method on the socket. Hope this helps.